# Print only last line of repetitive lines in UNIX

Tags: unix, awk, printing, lines

I have lines into file like this:

```
20170824 08:00:00 21.1804 22.1807
20170824 08:00:00 21.1805 22.1806
20170824 08:00:00 21.1804 22.1807
20170824 08:00:00 21.1805 22.1806
20170824 08:00:00 21.1804 22.1806
20170824 08:00:01 21.1803 22.1806
20170824 08:00:01 21.1804 22.1806
20170824 08:00:01 21.1803 22.1807
20170824 08:00:01 21.1803 22.1806
20170824 08:00:01 21.1803 22.1806
20170824 08:00:02 21.1803 22.1805
20170824 08:00:02 21.1804 22.1808
20170824 08:00:02 21.1804 22.1806
20170824 08:00:02 21.1804 22.1807
20170824 08:00:03 21.1804 22.1808
20170824 08:00:03 21.1803 22.1807
20170824 08:00:03 21.1803 22.1805
20170824 08:00:03 21.1804 22.1806
20170824 08:00:05 21.1804 22.1807
20170824 08:00:05 21.1804 22.1808
20170824 08:00:05 21.1805 22.1806
20170824 08:00:05 21.1804 22.1807
20170824 08:00:05 21.1805 22.1806
```

My aim is to print only the last line of the repetitive times.
For example, the output should be:

```
20170824 08:00:00 21.1804 22.1806
20170824 08:00:01 21.1803 22.1806
20170824 08:00:02 21.1804 22.1807
20170824 08:00:03 21.1804 22.1806
20170824 08:00:05 21.1805 22.1806
```

I can split the columns with some character to be able to use AWK.
Any idea for this?

Answer (score 3):

With GNU sort for `-s` (stable sort):

```
$ tac file | sort -k1,2 -su
20170824 08:00:00     21.1804     22.1806
20170824 08:00:01     21.1803     22.1806
20170824 08:00:02     21.1804     22.1807
20170824 08:00:03     21.1804     22.1806
20170824 08:00:05     21.1805     22.1806
```

Otherwise:

```
$ tac file | awk '!seen[$1,$2]++' | tac
20170824 08:00:00     21.1804     22.1806
20170824 08:00:01     21.1803     22.1806
20170824 08:00:02     21.1804     22.1807
20170824 08:00:03     21.1804     22.1806
20170824 08:00:05     21.1805     22.1806
```

Comment: Thank you!
What if the columns are comma separated and the time is as last column? Is there a way to have the same results?

Comment: Sure, just write a similarly trivial script to deal with whatever format you like. Post a new question if you'd like help with that.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{k=$1 FS $2} NR>1 && p!=k{print p0} {p0=$0; p=k} END{print}' file

20170824 08:00:00     21.1804     22.1806
20170824 08:00:01     21.1803     22.1806
20170824 08:00:02     21.1804     22.1807
20170824 08:00:03     21.1804     22.1806
20170824 08:00:05     21.1805     22.1806
```

**Explanation**

Set the key;
starting from the second line if key isn't equal to previous key print previous line;
save the current line and current key to be used in the next iteration;
print the last line.

Comment: Looks like its working, but is it possible to explain me shortly what the code is doing, because seems like the date column is last in another file and i need to tweak a little bit the code... Thank you!

Comment: It is like this actually (pipe delimited):

P=BIS  |  0  |  0  |  1.48  |  1.49  |  06/01/2016 16:00:01
P=BIS  |  0  |  0  |  1.48  |  1.49  |  06/01/2016 16:00:05
P=BIS  |  0  |  0  |  1.49  |  1.50  |  06/01/2016 16:00:07

Comment: code is very generic, you need to set the key based on your fields and field delimiter.

Comment: Yes, this is what i did and put this in my last comment down... still looking for what might be a problem....

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk '{k=$1 FS $2}!a[k]++ && r{print r}{ r=$0 }END{print}' file
```

- `k=$1 FS $2` - constructing a unique key concatenating `date` and `time` columns
- `!a[k]++ && r` - on encountering differing *date-time* `!a[k]++` and if there are previously processed lines `r` - print the last captured line `r=$0` from previous section

The output:

```
20170824 08:00:00 21.1804 22.1806
20170824 08:00:01 21.1803 22.1806
20170824 08:00:02 21.1804 22.1807
20170824 08:00:03 21.1804 22.1806
20170824 08:00:05 21.1805 22.1806
```

**----------**

***Bonus*** solution using GNU ***datamash*** tool:

```
datamash -Wt' ' -g 1,2 last 3 last 4 <file
```

- `g1,2` - group records by the 1st and 2nd fields which are *date-time* values
- `last 3 last 4` - means "output only the last entry from the 3rd and 4th field in each date-time group"

Comment: Looks like its working, but is it possible to explain me shortly what the code is doing, because seems like the date column is last in another file and i need to tweak a little bit the code... Thank you!

Comment: @AA21, see my explanation

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.
All answers were valuable for me...

**The problem now comes because I actually dont have "full" duplicates in the last (time) and first column, means it need somehow to be grouped by the first column and check the last column last value...

Any idea to fix this?**

21.1804   |   22.1807   |   20160324   |   16:00:09 
21.1805   |   22.1806   |   20160324   |   16:00:11  
21.1804   |   22.1807   |   20160324   |   16:00:25  
21.1805   |   22.1806   |   20160324   |   16:00:28  
21.1804   |   22.1806   |   20160324   |   16:00:47  
21.1803   |   22.1806   |   20160324   |   16:00:55  
21.1804   |   22.1806   |   20160324   |   16:01:03  
21.1803   |   22.1807   |   20160324   |   16:01:07  
21.1803   |   22.1806   |   20160324   |   16:01:25  
21.1803   |   22.1806   |   20160324   |   16:01:26  
21.1803   |   22.1805   |   20160324   |   16:01:40  
21.1804   |   22.1808   |   20160324   |   16:01:47  
21.1804   |   22.1806   |   20160324   |   16:01:55  
21.1804   |   22.1807   |   20160324   |   16:02:04  
21.1804   |   22.1808   |   20160324   |   16:02:07  
21.1803   |   22.1807   |   20160324   |   16:02:44  
21.1803   |   22.1805   |   20160324   |   16:02:56  
21.1804   |   22.1806   |   20160324   |   16:03:07  
21.1804   |   22.1807   |   20160324   |   16:03:14  
21.1804   |   22.1808   |   20160324   |   16:03:24  
21.1805   |   22.1806   |   20160324   |   16:03:46  
21.1804   |   22.1807   |   20160324   |   16:03:55  
21.1805   |   22.1806   |   20160324   |   16:04:03  
21.1804   |   22.1807   |   20160324   |   16:04:27  
21.1805   |   22.1806   |   20160324   |   16:04:28  
21.1804   |   22.1807   |   20160324   |   16:04:49  
21.1805   |   22.1806   |   20160324   |   16:04:17  
21.1804   |   22.1806   |   20160324   |   16:05:01  
21.1803   |   22.1806   |   20160324   |   16:05:03  
21.1804   |   22.1806   |   20160324   |   16:05:06  
21.1803   |   22.1807   |   20160324   |   16:05:11  
21.1803   |   22.1806   |   20160324   |   16:05:15  
21.1803   |   22.1806   |   20160324   |   16:05:24  
21.1803   |   22.1805   |   20160324   |   16:06:18  
21.1804   |   22.1808   |   20160324   |   16:06:24  
21.1804   |   22.1806   |   20160324   |   16:06:36  
21.1804   |   22.1807   |   20160324   |   16:06:40  
21.1804   |   22.1808   |   20160324   |   16:06:56  
21.1803   |   22.1807   |   20160324   |   16:07:00  
21.1803   |   22.1805   |   20160324   |   16:07:07  
21.1804   |   22.1806   |   20160324   |   16:07:22  
21.1804   |   22.1807   |   20160324   |   16:07:25  
21.1804   |   22.1808   |   20160324   |   16:08:15  
21.1805   |   22.1806   |   20160324   |   16:08:27  
21.1804   |   22.1807   |   20160324   |   16:08:39  
21.1805   |   22.1806   |   20160324   |   16:09:11  
21.1804   |   22.1807   |   20160324   |   16:09:25  
21.1805   |   22.1806   |   20160324   |   16:09:25  
21.1804   |   22.1807   |   20160324   |   16:09:38  
21.1805   |   22.1806   |   20160324   |   16:09:39  
21.1804   |   22.1806   |   20160324   |   16:09:47  
21.1803   |   22.1806   |   20160324   |   16:09:55  
21.1804   |   22.1806   |   20160324   |   16:09:56